# Jagged result of baked vertex color

Tags: texturing, shaders, texture-baking, uv-image-editor, vertex-colors

My model has vertex color.
I unwrap using Smart UV Project with default (Angle limit 66 and  Correct Aspect selected). In shading node, I linked Vectec Color (Col) > Principle BSDF > Material Output, and selected Image texture (point to previous unwrap image). I Then Bake using Device: GPU Compute, bake Type: Diffuse, Contribution: Color (only), Output > Margin: 0 px.
After bake, I apply the baked image but the result is some jagged line. After some experience, seem like the jagged come from Angle limit of 66 as changing it will result in different jagged.
Anyway to solve this?

[image]

Comment: Found the problem. Default 16px solve issue. Case close